# The difference between "=" and "IN" / "NOT IN" and "MINUS"

Tags: mysql, sql

Branch(branch_name, branch_city, assets)

Customer(customer_name, customer_street, customer_city)

Loan(loan_number, branch_name, amount)

Borrower(customer_name, loan_number)
Account(account_number, branch_name, balance)
Depositor(customer_name, account_number)

How are the "=" and "IN" and "NOT IN" and "MINUS" in

```
select c.customer_name
from Customer c, Borrower b, Loan l
where c.customer_city = 'Fairfax AND c.customer_name = b.customer_name 
                AND b.loan_number = l.loan_number
minus
select d.customer_name 
from Depositer d, Account a
where d.account_number = a.account_number
```

AND

```
select c.customer_name
from Customer c
where c.customer_city = 'Fairfax' AND c.customer_name in
    (select b.customer_name 
    from Borrower b
    where b.loan_number in
       (select l.loan_number 
       from Loan l
       where b.customer_name not in
           (select d.customer_name
           from Account a, Depositor d
           where a.account_number = d.account_number)))
```

different from each other? They should accomplish the same thing

Comment: In general... = operator is used for a single value check where as IN is used to do a multi-value check.

Comment: You are missing the declaration of `b` in the first query, might want to add that so people know where you are getting it from

Comment: Surprisingly ... or not ... these are covered in the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Answer (score 1):

One of the 'joys' of SQL is that the same relational operator (intersect, difference, etc) can be written using a variety of equivalent SQL constructs (which partially explains why SQL optimizers don't always pick the best plan without help from users).

Using these simple example tables:

```
WITH A AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS T (n)), 
     B AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (3), (4), (5)) AS T (n))
```

---

Intersection using `IN (<subquery>)`

```
SELECT n
  FROM A
 WHERE n IN ( SELECT n FROM B ) ;
```

Intersection using using quantified comparison

```
SELECT n
  FROM A
 WHERE n = ANY ( SELECT n FROM B ) ;
```

Intersection using `INTERSECT`

```
SELECT n
  FROM A
INTERSECT
SELECT n
  FROM B;
```

Intersection using `INTERSECT`, alternate syntax:

```
TABLE A 
INTERSECT 
TABLE B;
```

Intersection using `EXISTS (<subquery>)`

```
SELECT n
  FROM A
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
                  FROM B 
                 WHERE B.n = A.n 
              );
```

Intersection using join

```
SELECT n
  FROM A NATURAL JOIN B;
```

Intersection using `MATCH (<subquery>)`

```
SELECT n
  FROM A
 WHERE n MATCH ( SELECT n FROM B ) ;
```

---

Difference using `NOT IN (<subquery>)`

```
SELECT n
  FROM A
 WHERE n NOT IN ( SELECT n FROM B ) ;
```

Difference using using quantified comparison

```
SELECT n
  FROM A
 WHERE n <> ALL ( SELECT n FROM B ) ;
```

Difference using `EXCEPT` [`MINUS` in Oracle]

```
SELECT n
  FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT n
  FROM B;
```

Difference using `EXCEPT`, alternate syntax:

```
TABLE A 
EXCEPT 
TABLE B;
```

Difference using `NOT EXISTS (<subquery>)`

```
SELECT n
  FROM A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                      FROM B 
                     WHERE B.n = A.n 
                  );
```

Difference using join

```
SELECT A.n
  FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.n = B.n
 WHERE B.n IS NULL;
```

[SQL has no `NO MATCH` operator!]

Comment: That's a beautiful answer! Is there a collection of stuff like this? I would love to read more about rewriting queries in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used to compare against a single value, while `IN` is used to compare against several values. `NOT IN` would then just be the opposite, i.e. where it equals anything except these set of values, and `MINUS` is actually subtracting each result from the first sub-query from the second sub-query.

You can find more info about MINUS here: [MINUS keyword](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-minus.html)

Comment: Since when does MySQL support the `MINUS` operator? I just tried it in 5.5 and get an error (it also does not support the standard EXCEPT operator if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: "= is used to compare against a single value" -- I'm not sure that is correct: take a look at the "Intersection using using quantified comparison" example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE ... IN ...` allows you to search for a list of values, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `status` IN("placed", "processed", "fulfilled")
```

That's easier than writing this:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `status` = "placed" OR `status` = "processed" OR `status` = "fulfilled"
```

Especially when you don't know the "range" of possible values, or you want to combine that condition with other conditions (it gets nasty to have a lot of parenthetical conditions).  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders_items` WHERE `order_id` IN (
    SELECT `order_id` FROM `orders` WHERE `status` IN ("processed", "fulfilled")
)
```

Many times, a `JOIN` would be more appropriate (such in the last example), but `WHERE ... IN ...` is nice when you have an `ENUM` column, or a pre-defined list of possible filters.

`WHERE ... NOT IN ...` is the same, but negated.

To answer your actual question, well honestly I don't have time to see how those queries are different.  I would prefer the former query over the latter, if for nothing but readability.  I would almost always favor `JOIN`s over `WHERE IN` or `WHERE NOT IN` when you're dealing with primary key references (i.e. INT columns).